# How do I derive from hashlib.sha256 in Python?

Tags: python, security, cryptography

A naive attempt fails miserably:

```
import hashlib

class fred(hashlib.sha256):
    pass

-> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
       cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances
```

Well, it turns out that hashlib.sha256 is a callable, not a class.  Trying something a bit more creative doesn't work either:

```
 import hashlib

 class fred(type(hashlib.sha256())):
     pass

 f = fred

 -> TypeError: cannot create 'fred' instances
```

Hmmm...

So, how do I do it?

Here is what I want to actually achieve:

```
class shad_256(sha256):
    """Double SHA - sha256(sha256(data).digest())
Less susceptible to length extension attacks than sha256 alone."""
    def digest(self):
        return sha256(sha256.digest(self)).digest()
    def hexdigest(self):
        return sha256(sha256.digest(self)).hexdigest()
```

Basically I want everything to pass through except when someone calls for a result I want to insert an extra step of my own.  Is there a clever way I can accomplish this with `__new__` or metaclass magic of some sort?

I have a solution I'm largely happy with that I posted as an answer, but I'm really interested to see if anybody can think of anything better.  Either much less verbose with very little cost in readability or much faster (particularly when calling `update`) while still being somewhat readable.

**Update:** I ran some tests:

```
# test_sha._timehash takes three parameters, the hash object generator to use,
# the number of updates and the size of the updates.

# Built in hashlib.sha256
$ python2.7 -m timeit -n 100 -s 'import test_sha, hashlib' 'test_sha._timehash(hashlib.sha256, 20000, 512)'
100 loops, best of 3: 104 msec per loop

# My wrapper based approach (see my answer)
$ python2.7 -m timeit -n 100 -s 'import test_sha, hashlib' 'test_sha._timehash(test_sha.wrapper_shad_256, 20000, 512)'
100 loops, best of 3: 108 msec per loop

# Glen Maynard's getattr based approach
$ python2.7 -m timeit -n 100 -s 'import test_sha, hashlib' 'test_sha._timehash(test_sha.getattr_shad_256, 20000, 512)'
100 loops, best of 3: 103 msec per loop
```

Comment: What was -1 about my question?

Comment: Well, applying SHA256 twice won't reinforce security at all. if you have a collision on sha256 alone, then the digests are identical, so the second sha256 will generate the same hash. If you want security, you need to combines hashes, not chain them.

Comment: @BatchyX - You are not describing the type of attack I'm defending against.  In a length extension attack the attacker generates the internal hash algorithm state from the hash value and then feeds more data into the hash algorithm and generates a new hash.  This can allow an attacker to add data to a message in certain circumstances or do other nasty things.  I'm not expecting the new hash to be more collision resistant.  In fact, I'm a little worried it would be less.  But it definitely is much more resistant to length extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `__getattr__` to cause all attributes that you don't define yourself to fall back on the underlying object:

```
import hashlib

class shad_256(object):
    """
    Double SHA - sha256(sha256(data).digest())
    Less susceptible to length extension attacks than sha256 alone.

    >>> s = shad_256('hello world')
    >>> s.digest_size
    32
    >>> s.block_size
    64
    >>> s.sha256.hexdigest()
    'b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9'
    >>> s.hexdigest()
    'bc62d4b80d9e36da29c16c5d4d9f11731f36052c72401a76c23c0fb5a9b74423'
    >>> s.nonexistant()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    AttributeError: '_hashlib.HASH' object has no attribute 'nonexistant'
    >>> s2 = s.copy()
    >>> s2.digest() == s.digest()
    True
    >>> s2.update("text")
    >>> s2.digest() == s.digest()
    False
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
        if data is not None:
            self.update(data)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.sha256, key)

    def _get_final_sha256(self):
        return hashlib.sha256(self.sha256.digest())

    def digest(self):
        return self._get_final_sha256().digest()

    def hexdigest(self):
        return self._get_final_sha256().hexdigest()

    def copy(self):
        result = shad_256()
        result.sha256 = self.sha256.copy()
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

This mostly eliminates the overhead for `update` calls, but not completely.  If you want to completely eliminate it, add this to `__init__` (and correspondingly in `copy`):

```
self.update = self.sha256.update
```

That will eliminate the extra `__getattr__` call when looking up `update`.

This all takes advantage of one of the more useful and often overlooked properties of Python member functions: function binding.  Recall that you can do this:

```
a = "hello"
b = a.upper
b()
```

because taking a reference to a member function doesn't return the original function, but a binding of that function to its object.  That's why, when `__getattr__` above returns `self.sha256.update`, the returned function correctly operates on `self.sha256`, not `self`.

Comment: I need to test this a bit to compare the speed against what I'm doing.

Comment: With the `self.update` optimization, I find updates are exactly as fast as using `sha256` directly--as expected, since it's doing the same thing (a `__dict__` lookup and native function call).

Comment: I added some timing information.  Yours is very slightly better than mine.

Comment: I think I'm going to choose a combination of yours and mine (basically use your `update` optimization) because I like the fact that it's so easy to wrap a random hash function while preserving accurate doc strings with mine.

Comment: Your timing's "very slightly better" is the same speed as `sha256` itself, which means that's as good as it gets: zero overhead.  Aside from that (and more the point), implementing `__getattr__` like this is the simplest way to "subclass" objects like `sha256` which don't have an exposed class.  Don't know if there's something else you're looking for.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard - Nope.  :-)  And you're right.  The "very slightly better" is the same as the no overhead speed.  :-)

Comment: @Glenn Maynard - I updated my answer to reflect what I eventually decided to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Make a new class, derive from object, create a hashlib.sha256 member var in **init**, then define methods expected of a hash class and proxy to the same methods of the member variable.

Something like:

```
import hashlib

class MyThing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._hasher = hashlib.sha256()

    def digest(self):
        return self._hasher.digest()
```

And so on for the other methods.

Comment: Well, that would work.  I was hoping to do something more clever that involved less typing, because, you know, I'd rather type a whole bunch of text in StackOverflow then a bunch of repetitive method declarations.  :-)

Comment: You could override __getattr__ or __getattribute__ and proxy all calls down to the self._hasher variable, I suppose that would be a bit more clever.

Comment: @Adam Vandenberg, more clever but it would actually be much more verbose, because gettattr would have to conditionally apply function wrappers.

Comment: I posted what I eventually did as an answer, but if you can come up with something better I'm all ears.  It's actually similar to what you wrote here.

Comment: To me 'clever' is readable, simple code.  This answer is very clever. +1

Comment: +1  This is by far the most `Pythonic` answer and IMO the proper way of doing it. Here you are *essentially* subclassing a function by extending its capabilities through your own class... basically exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Scott - Yes, there is that.  And I do place a high value on readability.  I'm just interested in my options.  There is also the fact this class will be used in some tight loops that process a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

So, here is the answer I came up with that's based on Glen's answer, which is the one I awarded him the bounty for:

```
import hashlib

class _double_wrapper(object):
    """This wrapper exists because the various hashes from hashlib are
    factory functions and there is no type that can be derived from.
    So this class simulates deriving from one of these factory
    functions as if it were a class and then implements the 'd'
    version of the hash function which avoids length extension attacks
    by applying H(H(text)) instead of just H(text)."""

    __slots__ = ('_wrappedinstance', '_wrappedfactory', 'update')
    def __init__(self, wrappedfactory, *args):
        self._wrappedfactory = wrappedfactory
        self._assign_instance(wrappedfactory(*args))

    def _assign_instance(self, instance):
        "Assign new wrapped instance and set update method."
        self._wrappedinstance = instance
        self.update = instance.update

    def digest(self):
        "return the current digest value"
        return self._wrappedfactory(self._wrappedinstance.digest()).digest()

    def hexdigest(self):
        "return the current digest as a string of hexadecimal digits"
        return self._wrappedfactory(self._wrappedinstance.digest()).hexdigest()

    def copy(self):
        "return a copy of the current hash object"
        new = self.__class__()
        new._assign_instance(self._wrappedinstance.copy())
        return new

    digest_size = property(lambda self: self._wrappedinstance.digest_size,
                           doc="number of bytes in this hashes output")
    digestsize = digest_size
    block_size = property(lambda self: self._wrappedinstance.block_size,
                          doc="internal block size of hash function")

class shad_256(_double_wrapper):
    """
    Double SHA - sha256(sha256(data))
    Less susceptible to length extension attacks than SHA2_256 alone.

    >>> import binascii
    >>> s = shad_256('hello world')
    >>> s.name
    'shad256'
    >>> int(s.digest_size)
    32
    >>> int(s.block_size)
    64
    >>> s.hexdigest()
    'bc62d4b80d9e36da29c16c5d4d9f11731f36052c72401a76c23c0fb5a9b74423'
    >>> binascii.hexlify(s.digest()) == s.hexdigest()
    True
    >>> s2 = s.copy()
    >>> s2.digest() == s.digest()
    True
    >>> s2.update("text")
    >>> s2.digest() == s.digest()
    False
    """
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(shad_256, self).__init__(hashlib.sha256, *args)
    name = property(lambda self: 'shad256', doc='algorithm name')
```

This is a little verbose, but results in a class that works very nicely from a documentation perspective and has a relatively clear implementation.  With Glen's optimization, `update` is as fast as it possibly can be.

There is one annoyance, which is that the `update` function shows up as a data member and doesn't have a docstring.  I think that's a readability/efficiency tradeoff that's acceptable.

Comment: This is pretty much write-only, isn't it?

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis - Yes, but it does mean I have very little extra code to write for any other hash function.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis - I fixed it so it no longer has the 'write-only' property nearly so strongly.

Answer (score 0):

```
from hashlib import sha256

class shad_256(object):
    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self._hash = sha256(data)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        setattr(self, attr, getattr(self._hash, attr))
        return getattr(self, attr)

    def copy(self):
        ret = shad_256()
        ret._hash = self._hash.copy()
        return ret

    def digest(self):
        return sha256(self._hash.digest()).digest()

    def hexdigest(self):
        return sha256(self._hash.digest()).hexdigest()
```

Any attributes that are not found on an instance are bound lazily by `__getattr__`. `copy()` needs to be treated specially of course.

Comment: This is basically identical to Glenn Maynard's answer.